# Division of Bernoulli's lemniscate by ruler and compass

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry, galois-theory, analytic-geometry, elliptic-functions

Bernoulli's lemniscate with unit half-width is given by the polar equation $r=\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$. Using this curve, in the first quadrant, we define the function $\operatorname{arcsl}$ according to this figure[image] (the author is Jacob Rus on Wikipedia) and the function $\operatorname{sl}$ as its inverse. The definition of the function $\operatorname{sl}$ can be extended to all real numbers (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_elliptic_functions for more details).

Let $2\varpi$ be the perimeter of the lemniscate $r=\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$. The *n-division points* of the lemniscate are the points dividing it to arcs of equal length. It can be proved that

> The n-division points can be constructed using only straightedge and compass iff $n=2^r p_1\cdots p_m$ where $r$ is a non-negative integer and each $p_i$ is a distinct Fermat prime.

The problem of constructibility of the n-division points can be translated to the language of algebra as the problem of determining for what $n$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\operatorname{sl}\frac{2\varpi k}{n}, (k\in\{1,\ldots,n\})$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ a power of two. **However, this uses the tacit assumption that the origin is a division point.** (since for $k=n$ we get $\operatorname{sl}2\varpi=0$.)

If we drop this assumption, does the theorem still hold true? If it does, why?

In his book *Galois theory*, Cox ignores this subtlety. On p. 464, he writes

> Here, the n-division points of the lemniscate are obtained as follows. **Begin at the origin** and follow the curve into the first quadrant, down into the fourth quadrant [...]

Note that "begin at the origin" is the case $k=n$. The question is what if one doesn't begin at the origin?

Comment: I think the assumption is crucial. The same assumption is made for division of circle also but due to the symmetry of circle one can use any two perpendicular diameters as the coordinate axes. In case of lemniscate there is only one diameter.